# Create temporary data or table in sql and use as a database

Tags: sql, database, pycharm, connection, typeerror

I tried to create a temporary sql data(table) with same fields as in the original database.
What I tried..

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
database = os.path.join(dirname, "database/database.db")
conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
cursor = conn.cursor()
stm = cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT * FROM database;")

#and also tried with some  selected fields like following

 stm = cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE new_table(pressure int,parameter varchar(20),day int,month int,latitude int,longitude int,surface int);")
                       
 tables = cursor.execute("INSERT into new_table SELECT pressure,parameter, day,month,latitude,longitude,surface FROM database;")
```

And the error is,

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SELECT": syntax error
```

How to create a new data table with selected tables or all tables(only) from the original database.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your first create table you need to define it with an "as".

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM database);
```

This should clear up your error.

Comment: Thank you, Sam, for your valuable time, Unfortunately, I'm getting some errors again. I tried stm = c.execute("CREATE TABLE temp AS ( SELECT * FROM database);") and I'm getting some syntax error, Can you show me where I made mistake!!